# How can a user related to an Organization login and be restricted so they only see related members of the organisation

Tags: civimember, contacts, permissions, relationships

With CiviCrm can you manage accesses of single organization, set user and password for this single organization, and show only individuals related this organization, and only manage related membership of this organization?
Thanks

Comment: can someone help me?

Comment: I had a go at changing the title of this thread to make it more helpful, but i may have missed the point. hopefully not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to answer though the english version of your question may mean i guess wrongly.

if the goal is to have John connected to organisation First Co, and Mary connected to organisation Second Co, then yes it is possible that when John logs in he is restricted to seeing only contacts connected to First Co and will not see those connected only to Second Co., and the opposite will apply for Mary.

EDIT: To do this you need to apply Access Control ACL  and the way to do that will depend a bit on the general purposes of your site.

One option for example is that you can set ACLs to work on Relationships (I can provide more detail on this) so that for example John or anyone else who is an 'officer' of First Co can then access anyone who is an 'employee' of First Co.

To achieve the latter involves [installing extensions](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Extensions). In this case the [Related Permissions extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls) and the extension that it depends on, [CiviCRM Entity Settings](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-entity-settings).

When the above extensions are enabled, on any Relationship Type you should now see a new field saying Always Permission A to B (and vv). And at civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1 you should see an option for 'Allow second-degree relationship permissions'.

Comment: ok thank'you . Which particular permission i have to enable?

Comment: see the 'edit' above

Comment: When I active the extension "Related permission extension", what area will be enabled within the users and permissions? Thnak'you

Comment: I will enable this? : "Allow second-degree relationship permissions" radio button at Administer->System settings->Misc .

Comment: Relationship Permissions as ACLs don't work on my versione 4.6.11

Comment: you installed and enabled the CiviCRM Entity extension as well?

Comment: I copied the files in a folder and I enabled "Related Permissions extension"

Comment: Sorry, now i have install "CiviCRM Entities" module of drupal, and "CiviCrm Entity Setting" , but this last is for version 4.5. and now? thank'you

Comment: I believe the latter is fine for 4.6. i don't think you need the Drupal CiviCRM Entities module

Comment: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-entity-settings   for CiviCRM 4.2, CiviCRM 4.4, CiviCRM 4.5

Comment: i know it only lists up to 4.5 but that does not mean it does not work for 4.6

Comment: I want to understand where is the section that enables ? thank'you

Comment: being answered in http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9312/relationship-permissions-as-acls-dont-work/9330?noredirect=1#comment9126_9330

Comment: Perfect!!! It works ! thank you, you're so kind

Comment: Great - can you pls 'accept' this answer then as it indicates to others what the solution is.

Comment: Ok for setting Relationship go to :  administer > customise data and screens > relationship types.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35238/discussion-between-andrea-and-petednz-fuzion).

Comment: now, how can I associate a particular organization to a role ? Can you help me? pls

Comment: Pls read the Manual http://book.civicrm.org/user/organising-your-data/relationships/